# Where do I get the missing resources?

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror, box-api

I am still unable to get the box-api [hello world program](https://github.com/box/box-java-sdk-v2/wiki/HelloWorld) to work.  I was getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang/NotImplementedException
    at TestProgram.getAuthenticatedClient(TestProgram.java:47)
    at TestProgram.main(TestProgram.java:35)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.lang.NotImplementedException
    ...
```

I then went to the [Apache Commons Lang Home](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) and downloaded and set up their thing.

Now I get

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper
    at com.box.boxjavalibv2.jacksonparser.BoxResourceHub.<init>(BoxResourceHub.java:28)
    at com.box.boxjavalibv2.BoxClient.createResourceHub(BoxClient.java:345)
    at com.box.boxjavalibv2.BoxClient.<init>(BoxClient.java:65)
    ...
```

and I have no idea how to fulfill that dependency.  I also suspect that even if I could find this one, there'd just be another one, and another one, and another one.  Manually importing them all does not seem to be very realistic.

**How am I intended to get the missing dependencies for the box API?**

Comment: Which IDE are you using?

Comment: From [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/)?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I am using eclipse.

Comment: Right click on your project and choose *Build Path / Configure Build Path...* Then go to the *Libraries* tab and select *Add JARs...*, choose the jar(s) in your project you want to add. To be more cautious about this, it would be better if you create a *lib* folder inside your project and drop all the jars and dependencies there.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza That's really not what I meant.  I want to know how I am intended to acquire the jars to be added, or something.  Am I supposed to just keep looking up the libraries until I have them all, or am I supposed to be using some sort of automatic dependency resolver tool to collect and download them all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SDK comes included with all of the dependencies you should need. You can find them all in [the libs directory](https://github.com/box/box-java-sdk-v2/tree/master/BoxJavaLibraryV2/libs) of the SDK..

Add all of those jars to your Eclipse build path and it should work.